# SpaCy for detecting merchant name

Tags: nlp, spacy

I'm quite new in the NLP world and the spaCy is the first tool I'm facing with.

I need to autodetect a merchant name from the bank SMS messages.
For instance:
"Payment of 4,10 EUR in **FARMACIA LITORAL** with your card ending in 1234 accepted."
or
"Paid €3.77 at **AliExpress** Spent today: €3.77"

My first thought was to use Named Entity and detect "ORG" or "GPE" tags but it doesn't works for abbreviations and cuts like "AMZN MKTP" or  "ASICS FO".

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
doc = nlp("Paid €3.77 at AMZN MKTP Spent today: €3.77")

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
```

3.77 6 10 MONEY
today 30 35 DATE
3.77 38 42 MONEY

Advise please in what direction to move?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of using NER models is a good one, but your model selection could be suboptimal, maybe try out some NER models from Huggingface such as [bert-base-NER-uncased](https://huggingface.co/dslim/bert-base-NER-uncased)

Additionally, it could be useful to use an algorithmic approach alongside NER. Banks are generating messages with a template, so you could create rules to extract merchants from those templates.

Finally, you could try to find a merchant database and match merchants using hash, but that would probably work best just as a double-check approach for already detected entities.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The SpaCy has multilingual support which is important for me. It looks like the bert-base-NER-uncased us EN only